# Storing an image with PHP PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello friends of the community.
I'm storing information in my MySQL database using this code:

```
class crud
    {
        private $db;

        function __construct($DB_con)
        {
            $this->db = $DB_con;
        }

        public function create($fname,$lname,$email,$contact,$nimagen)
        {
            try
            {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(first_name,last_name,email_id,contact_no) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :email, :contact)");
                $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
                $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
                $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
                $stmt->bindparam(":contact",$contact);
                $stmt->execute();
                return true;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();  
                return false;
            }

        }   

}
```

Now I want to add a picture, Please I need to add in the code?
I'm using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the image in database table may not be a good idea.
As database size will grow heavily, instead store the files in some folder on server & store the filename(url of the file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your image as a blob.

```
$file = fopen('path/to/image.jpg','rb');

$stmt->bindparam(":image", $file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
```

Edit: Since others have pointed this out I thought I'd just say it's probably best to avoid doing this and store your image in the filesystem,  instead saving the filename in the database so you can reference your image that way. But this should answer your question regardless.

Comment: This might not be a good idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: I'm not saying storing images in a database is a good idea, I never do it. But that's not the question that's being asked.

Comment: which role does 'rb'?

Comment: Generally speaking you use rb to read non-text files and r to read text files.

Comment: ok, thanks Dontfeedthecode, but better is to put the path to a varchar field and name of the file to another varchar field.

Comment: Please, what should I do?

Comment: That's the general idea, you don't need to store the path either you can just set the path to your image directory as a constant in PHP and append the filename from your db to it.

Comment: Happy to have helped, if that's answered your question feel free to select this as the correct answer :)